# Custom Model Binder Provider always null .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I'm having a problem trying to get custom model binders to work as a query parameter like I have gotten to work previously in .net framework 4.7.

To ensure this wasn't a scenario where my object was too complex, I reduced the model to a simple string but even then I cannot get this to work.

I have a simple model I would like to be binded from query parameters.

```
public class SearchModel {
    public string SearchTerms { get; set; }
}
```

And I have configured the ModelBinder and ModelBinderProvider as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) like so.

```
public class TestModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(SearchModel)) {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid binding context supplied {bindingContext.ModelType}");
        }

        var model = (SearchModel)bindingContext.Model ?? new SearchModel();

        var properties = model.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach(var p in properties) {
            var value = this.GetValue(bindingContext, p.Name);
            p.SetValue(model, Convert.ChangeType(value, p.PropertyType), null);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected string GetValue(ModelBindingContext context, string key) {
        var result = context.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);

        return result.FirstValue;
    }
}

public class TestModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider {
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context) {
        if (context == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(SearchModel)) {
            var returnType = new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(TestModelBinder));
            return returnType;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

As stated in the last step in Microsoft documentation I updated my ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs to include the BinderProvider.

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
            options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new TestModelBinderProvider());
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

But when I call my Search endpoint with a url such as "https://localhost:44387/api/testbinding?searchTerms=newSearch" I am always seeing a return of "request == null True" even though I see it properly hit the custom binding and bind correctly if I step through debugging, can anyone please point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestBindingController : ControllerBase {

    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult GetResult([FromQuery] SearchModel request) {
        return Ok($"request == null {request == null}");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're missing if the statement that sets the result of the model binding operation, as you can see in the `AuthorEntityBinder` code sample in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#custom-model-binder-sample) of the docs:

```cs
bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
```

Your implementation of the model binder does create an instance of `SearchModel`, but doesn't *feed it back* to the model binding context.

---

As a separate note, I don't think you need to add a custom model binder is the query string segments match the properties names of the model you're trying to bind.

Comment: Thank you so much Mickaël, always helpful to get a second pair of eyes. :) You are correct in both aspects of your answer. I was missing that line to properly send the model back to the context, and I wouldn't _need_ to do this for regular binding as this is supported in .net core however my final project will need an alias binding implementation so I needed to get this to work (for instance searchTerms can be replaced with simply 'q'). I am set now!

Comment: Happy it worked! Now, the model binding system is quite flexible in MVC, so it supports aliasing by default. You could decorate the `SearchTerms` property with `[BindProperty(Name = "q")]` to instruct the model bindng system it needs to source the value of that property from a request value that has a different name. You can also specify where the value needs to come from: request body, route values, query string, etc... I suggest that you read the official docs on the matter, they're pretty good: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1